# Wiper fluid sprayer no longer works on Nissan Sunny 1997. Could it be a blown fuse?

Tags: windshield-wipers, fuse

When I try to activate the wiper fluid spray on the front windscreen of my car, the sprayer pump no longer activates (the wipers do though, after a short delay). It's quite a noisy pump, so I'd hear it running if the fluid had run out.

Could this be caused by a blown fuse?

I have a multimeter, which I'd guess could be used to check the fuses (hopefully they'll be labelled)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be a blown fuse as you suggest.

It could also be that the motor isn't receiving current due to a break in the wiring. The multimeter should come in handy to verify this - check to confirm that a voltage drop registers across the pump motor terminals when the wiper stalk is engaged.

It may also be that the motor in the pump has gone bad - check for continuity across the motor terminals.

Comment: In the end I ran out of time to solve this myself and took it to an auto-electrician. He said if it was a fuse causing the issue then the wipers wouldn't be working still. He replaced the pump with a second hand one and I was good to go. Cost was about NZ$90 (ouch). Thanks very much for your advice!